# How to convert this SQL query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am converting an asp.net app to .net core 6. I need help with an SQL query that needs to be converted into LINQ for Entity Framework.

Tables:

```
 Registration:
   regID,
   userID,
   courseID,
   numOfClass,     (num of class/hours registered) 
(A student, userID, could register multiple different courses)

 TeacherStudent:
   tsID,
   regID,
(The registered student is assigned to an instructor)

 Schedule:
   scheduleID,
   tsID,
   startDT,        (a class's starting date/time)
   endDT,          (a class's ending date/time)
   statusID,       (a class's status: 2200 for newly scheduled classes, 2210 for done classes, 2260 for student absent classes)
(The instructor schedules the classes into this table for this student. For each registered course, up to numOfClass classes can be scheduled. For example, if a student registered a course for 30 classes/hours, up to 30 records can be created in the Schedule table for this registered course.)
```

The desired query is: For a given student (userId), gets the statistics data for each course this student has taken so far in the following format:

courseId, course start date/time, course end date/time (for ongoing course, it is the latest class date/time), number of classes registered, number of classes scheduled, number of classes done, number of classes student is absent

In SQL Server, the statistics data can be returned by this query:

```sql
SELECT R.regID, R.courseID, MIN(S.startDT) AS startDT,  MAX(S.endDT) AS endDT, AVG(R.numOfClass) AS allCourseHours, SUM(CASE WHEN S.statusID = '2200' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS newCourseHours, SUM(CASE WHEN S.statusID = '2210' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS doneCourseHours, SUM(CASE WHEN S.statusID = '2260' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS studentAbsentCourseHours

FROM Registration AS R JOIN TeacherStudent AS T ON R.regID = T.regID JOIN Schedule AS S ON S.tsID = T.tsID

WHERE R.UserId = 100

GROUP BY R.regId, R.courseId
```

Now, in Entity Framework, how can we get the same statistics data with a LING query?

Answer (score 0):

I created a Model and then wrote the query

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context dbContext = new Context();

            var results = (from r in dbContext.Registration.Where(x => x.userID == "100")
                           join t in dbContext.TeacherStudent on r.regID equals t.regID
                           join s in dbContext.Schedule on t.tsID equals s.tsID
                           select new { r = r, t = t, s = s }
                           ).GroupBy(x => new { regid = x.r.regID, courseid = x.r.courseID })
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               regID = x.Key.regid,
                               courseID = x.Key.courseid,
                               startDT = x.Min(y => y.s.startDT),
                               endDT = x.Max(y => y.s.endDT),
                               allCourseHours = x.Average(y => y.r.numOfClass),
                               newCourseHours = x.Where(y => y.s.statusID == "2200").Count(),
                               doneCourseHours = x.Where(y => y.s.statusID == "2210").Count(),
                               studentAbsentCourseHours = x.Where(y => y.s.statusID == "2260").Count()
                           }).ToList();
 
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<Registration> Registration { get; set; }
        public List<TeacherStudent> TeacherStudent { get; set; }
        public List<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
    }
    public class Registration
    {
        public string regID { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public string courseID { get; set; }
        public int numOfClass { get; set; } 
    }
    public class TeacherStudent
    {
        public string tsID { get; set; }
        public string regID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Schedule
    {
        public string scheduleID { get; set; }
        public string tsID { get; set; }
        public DateTime startDT { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDT { get; set; }
        public string statusID { get; set; }
    
}
```